# `sklearn` asking for eval dataset when there is one

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I am working on Stacking Regressor from `sklearn` and I used `lightgbm` to train my model. My `lightgbm` model has an early stopping option and I have used eval dataset and metric for this.

When it feeds into the `StackingRegressor`, I saw this error

`ValueError: For early stopping, at least one dataset and eval metric is required for evaluation`

Which is frustrating because I do have them in my code. I wonder what is happening? Here's my code.

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingRegressor

opt_parameters_LGBM = {'bagging_fraction': 0.37031434827212084, 'bagging_seed': 47, 'boosting_type': 'gbdt', 
                       'feature_fraction': 0.3894822966866982, 'learning_rate': 0.01, 'max_bin': 177, 'max_depth': -1, 
                       'metric': 'rmse', 'min_child_weight': 1000.0, 'num_leaves': 161, 'objective': 'regression', 
                       'random_state': 47, 'reg_alpha': 10, 'reg_lambda': 50, 'verbosity': -1}  
m1 = lgb.LGBMRegressor(valid_sets = [lgb_train, lgb_eval], verbose_eval = 30, num_boost_round = 10000, early_stopping_rounds = 10, n_jobs=4, n_estimators=3000, **opt_parameters_LGBM)
m1.fit(X_train_df, y_train_df, eval_set = (X_val_df, y_val_df), eval_metric = 'rmse')

opt_parameters_ADA = {'learning_rate': 0.03, 'n_estimators': 5} 
m2 = AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=1, min_impurity_decrease=10, random_state=47), random_state=47, **opt_parameters_ADA)
m2.fit(X_train_df, y_train_df)

'''
Where problem starts
'''

gbm = xgb.XGBRegressor(
 learning_rate = 0.02,
 n_estimators= 5,
 max_depth= 4,
 min_child_weight= 2,
 gamma=0.9,                        
 subsample=0.8,
 colsample_bytree=0.8,
 objective= 'reg:squaredlogerror',
 nthread= -1,
 verbosity=3,
 random_state=20)

estimators = [('lgbm', m1), ('ada', m2)]

gbm = StackingRegressor(estimators=estimators, final_estimator=gbm, cv=5, verbose=1)
gbm.fit(X_train_df, y_train_df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I guess the issue is causing by the fact that `early_stopping` was used in the `LGBMRegressor`, thus it expects eval data in `StackingRegressor()` as well.*

#### Try doing the following:

Just after the line you've fitted your `LGBMRegressor()` model with the following line - `m1.fit(X_train_df, y_train_df, eval_set = (X_val_df, y_val_df), eval_metric = 'rmse')`, add these lines after that.

```
params = m1.get_params()

# remove early_stopping_rounds as your model is already fitted the data
params["early_stopping_rounds"] = None
m1.set_params(**params)
```

see if the error goes away.

Comment: I tried it seems that the `StackingRegressor()` doesn't accept this as an argument.

Comment: You're right, I've gone through the docs, It doesn't accept it. Never mind, I've updated the answer, try doing that way, hope it works.